# Is there an efficient way to solve this discrete optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, dynamic-programming

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be positive integers with $1\leqslant a_i\leqslant M$ for each $i$ ($M$ being a fixed positive integer greater than $1$), and $C$ a positive integer with $C>M$. I want to solve the integer program
\begin{align}
\max &\quad\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad Cx_j\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n a_iy_{ij},\quad 1\leqslant j\leqslant n\\
&\quad \sum_{j=1}^n y_{ij} \leqslant 1,\quad 1\leqslant i\leqslant n\\
&\quad x_j\in\{0,1\},\quad 1\leqslant j\leqslant n\\
&\quad y_{ij}\in\{0,1\},\quad 1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n
\end{align}
In my particular application, $M=19$ and $C=40$. So for example, if $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=15$ and $a_5=a_6=a_7=a_8=6$ then an optimal solution would be 
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 1\\
x_2 &= 1\\
y_{11} &= 1\\
y_{12} &= 1\\
y_{15} &= 1\\
y_{16} &= 1\\
y_{23} &= 1\\
y_{24} &= 1\\
y_{27} &= 1\\
y_{28} &= 1\\
\end{align}
I'm thinking there should be some sort of dynamic programming approach that would be relatively straightforward to implement (as opposed to actually solving the IP).

Comment: Is there a typo in your formulation? The way it is currently stated, the optimal objective is simply $0$ because $\sum_{j=1}^{n}{y_{ij}} \leq 1$ implies $\sum_{j=1}^{n}{a_j y_{ij}} \leq M$ and $C > M$, $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ implies $x_i = 0$, $\forall i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$.

Comment: @madnessweasley Thanks, I have corrected the formulation.

Comment: The optimal solution to your example still doesn't seem correct.

Comment: It looks like $i$ and $j$ should be switched in the constraints and $C$ should be lowered to $36$ for the given solution to be correct.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I meant for there to be two $15$'s and two $6$'s.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid solving it as an IP because you don't want to mess with IP solver software, or because you think DP would be more efficient? You can certainly turn it into a DP, but I'm inclined to think the state space would be annoyingly large for a decent size instance.

Comment: Well in the application I'm working with, $M=19$ and $C=40$. That's not particularly large. I'm trying to avoid solving it as an IP because it seems like there should be a more efficient way to do this.